# How to looping a game tracking characters?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to create a simple C++ looping game where 2 human players, taking turns, type in a sequence of letters and must match the last letter in the sequence to their first or they lose.

For example, if player 1 types in : hey
player 2 types in: you, player 1 types in: use, and if player 2 types in: hey, player 2 will lose because he did not start his sequence of letters with the last letter player 1 typed in (which was the 'e' in use).

**My problem in my code is I do not know how to make the program track the last letters and first letters inputted by each player to determine the winner.**

***My code:***

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        string word;
        string word2;
        bool userTurn = true;
        cout << "Welcome to the last letter/first letter game! ";
        cout << " Do you want to play first (y/n)? ";
        char response;
        if (!(cin >> response)) die("input failure");
        response = static_cast<char>(toupper(response));
        if (response == 'Y')
            userTurn = true;
        else if (response == 'N')
            userTurn = false;
        else
            die(" youre suppose to answer y or n");

        while (true){
            if (userTurn){
                cout << "Player #1: " << endl;
                cin >> word;

                    cout << "Player #2: " << endl;
                    cin >> word2;
            } if (userTurn && word != word2){
                cout << " Player 2 Wins! ";
            }
            } userTurn != userTurn;
        }
```

Comment: Does for example plyer2 know the word entered by player1? And what should be done if either player calls a word that already was used?

Comment: I have a better code!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll advice to use a OOP procedures for this program.

The test program demonstrates tracking the first and last characters of each run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{ 
    std::string word1, word2;
    char last, first;

    std::cout << "player1: ";
    std::cin >> word1;

    last = word1[word1.length() - 1]; //last character of player 1
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "player2: ";
        std::cin >> word2;

        first = word2[0];  //first character of player 2

        if (first != last)
        {
            std::cout << "player2 loss" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        last = word2[word2.length() - 1]; //last character of player 2

        std::cout << "player1: ";
        std::cin >> word1;

        first = word1[0];  //first character of player 1

        if (first != last)
        {
            std::cout << "player1 loss" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the first/last character of `std::string`, use `std::string::front()`/`std::string::back()` e. g. `word.back() != word2.front()`.

Also, try to make friends with google in the future. You'd find a solution, although not by the title you gave your question that doesn't have to do anything with your problem.

Comment: Thank you!! I was not aware of that type of function!

Comment: @Beezy I see you haven't accepted any answers to your questions. Why wouldn't you? Time to change that.